# Получение файла с telegram bot через aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Как можно скачать файл xlsx отправленный боту человеком?Есть бот которому должны скидывать файл xlsx, а он уже преобразовать в определенном стилистике в формат pdf преобразование готово через openpyxl, а вот с получением файла есть проблемы.

```
@dp.message(F.content_type == ContentType.DOCUMENT)
async def get_doc(message: types.Message):
    file_id = message.document.file_id
    print(file_id)

    await Bot.download(bot,file_id,"test.xlsx",120)
```

Этот кусок кода прекрасно скачивает файлы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу только подсказать, как сохранить файл по определенному пути:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.DOCUMENT)
async def get_doc(message: types.Message):
    name = message.document.file_id[1:10] #для уникальности файлов
    path = rf"МЕСТО КУДА СОХРАНЯЕШЬ\documents\{name}.xlsx" #там создается папка documents, туда и будут сохраняться файлы
    await message.document.download(destination_file=path)
```

Дальше, думаю, можно работать с путями, главное надо указать путь сохранения, ну еще и `state` подключить, если нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, этот код не работает под aiogram 3, но я его немного переделал и приложил в вопрос.

Comment: @user580418 ага я просто сам со второй версией работаю